# the validator shows this error when i try to make "ul" as a child of "ol" Or vice versa

Tags: html, validation, nested, syntax-error

i tried to check my code in a validator and it shows this message
the code:

```
<ol>
  <li>learn html. </li>
  <li>learn css. </li>
  <li>learn python. </li>
  <li>save the world. </li>
  <ul>
    <li>be patient.</li>
    <li>improve your skills</li>
  </ul>
```

the error message:

> "Element ol not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) "

I understand what does it mean but i dont know why it doesnt allowed and how i write it without errors

I tried to allign the nesting well and didnt work ,i am a beginner in coding by the way.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#nesting_lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `<ul>` or `<ol>` must be a child of a `<li>`: Try this:

```html
<ol>
  <li>learn html. </li>
  <li>learn css. </li>
  <li>learn python. </li>
  <li>save the world. </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>be patient.</li>
      <li>improve your skills</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: it worked. i am very greatfull , thank you.